# Antlr4 using C# - ini parser - parse the value of a key that is a key to another value

Tags: c#, parsing, recursion, antlr4, ini

How do I parse an *.INI file that has a value of a key as a key to another value using C#?

Example:

```
[PROJECT]
SUBPROJECT={$PROJECT_NAME_{$INI-FILE-DEFAULT-NAME$}$}_subproject
PROJECT_NAME_109={$INI-FILE-DEFAULT-NAME$}
INI-FILE-DEFAULT-NAME=109
```

Explication:

```
[section]
key= {$value$}
{$value$} = {$value2$}
{$value2$} = text
```

I am not able to get the text from key "value2". 
With my current implementation I am only able to get the text from key "value". I want to get the text from key "value2" and put it at the key "key" by parsing each key.

Expected:

```
[PROJECT]
SUBPROJECT=109_subproject
PROJECT_NAME_109=109
INI-FILE-DEFAULT-NAME=109
```

Antlr grammar file:

```
grammar StatusFile;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
file: (ini)+ EOF
    ;

ini : section (option)* 
    ;

section : STRING eol+                                                   
        ;

option : key '=' value* eol+                # assign
       ; 

eol :  WS
    ;

key : STRING
    ;

value : OPEN_ACOLADE value* CLOSE_ACOLADE               #Token
      | STRING                                          #String
      ;

WS : ( '\r\n' )+;

OPEN_ACOLADE : '{$' ;
CLOSE_ACOLADE : '$}' ;

STRING  : ( 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '_' | '0' .. '9' | '/' | '\\' | ':' | '*' 
            | '.' | ',' | ' ' | '-' | '<' | '>' | '!' | '+' | '"' | '#' | '(' | ')' 
            | '?' | '%' | '&' | '[' | ']' | '|' | ';' | '\'' | '~' | '^' | '`' )+ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an [INI library](https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini) that has this feature, I call it value binding, but instead of `{$NAME$}` it uses `@{NAME}` placeholders.

For example, for the following INI content:

```
[PROJECT]
PROJECTNAME109=@{INIFILEDEFAULTNAME}
INIFILEDEFAULTNAME=109
```

And the following C# code:

```
var ini = new IniFile();
ini.Load("sample.ini");

ini.ValueBinding.Bind();

foreach (var sec in ini.Sections)
    foreach (var key in sec.Keys)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", key.Name, key.Value);
```

The result is:

```
PROJECTNAME109=109
INIFILEDEFAULTNAME=109
```

However, it currently doesn't allow placeholder names with '-' characters (only letters) and it currently doesn't handle nested placeholders (e.g. `@{NAME@{NAME}}`).
But nevertheless, let me know if you're interested in using it as a solution and I'll add a support for that as well.